# What do the phase space and slope fields of the iodine clock reaction look like?

Tags: kinetics

The [iodine clock reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine_clock_reaction) is a fun experiment shown to undergraduates to illustrate that chemical reactions can show periodic behaviour. Presumably, or hopefully, there is a [system of differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_differential_equations) for this system that can be studied qualitatively. Some qualitative approaches are visual, including [slope fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_field) and [phase diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space). An example of a qualitatively discoverable property of a system is the existence of [attractors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor).

Has someone made visualizations of the phase space or slope fields for the differential equations governing the iodine clock reaction?